# React Native(Android) Scan QRCode

Tags: android, qr-code, react-native

I wanna write a native module for to scan barcode but it too hard for me to figure out a way to handle the result without adding a method to the MainActivity. It's not a good idea to modify the MainActivity such heavily because it's no easy job for application developers who writes javascript to use the module. 
For example, if I use ZXing Android Embedded: https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded, I have to add a method to MainActivity to handle the result.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(result != null) {
        if(result.getContents() == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Scanned: " + result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        // This is important, otherwise the result will not be passed to the fragment
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

That makes an issue that any one who uses this module has to modify their MainActivity, which means the module is hard to use. So, any ideas to work it out?

Comment: Can you add some code to help explain what the problem is?

Comment: @Isaac Madwed Details have been added to explain the problem. Thx for your attention.

Comment: hi! did u figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [react-native-rn-zxing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rn-zxing):

```
npm i react-native-rn-zxing
```

then link it :

```
react-native link react-native-rn-zxing
```

And enjoy